# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "builder" and "bundler":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I've started using ruby only a couple of days back. I don't understand the concept of gemfile fully. My Gemfile looks like:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'sunspot_solr', github: 'sunspot/sunspot', branch: 'master'
gem 'sunspot_rails', github: 'sunspot/sunspot', branch: 'master'
```

But on running "bundle install".

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "builder":
  In Gemfile:
    sunspot_rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      builder (~> 2.1.2) ruby

    sunspot_rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      builder (3.2.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    sunspot_rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.3.5)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

Which version of builder should I install, as there is a conflict,

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?  `ruby --version` should give you the answer.

Comment: @vgoff : I'm using 1.9.2

Comment: Try leaving only `sunspot_solr`.

Comment: @zrl3dx : It works, but i want to be able to use "rails generate sunspot_rails:install".

Comment: But you should be able to do it without `sunspot_solr` as it is now part of `sunspor_solr`. At least I have that task in one of my projects where I've only 'suunspot_solr' im Gemfile.

Comment: @zrl3dx : I get a "GemLoadError" if I use "rails generate sunspot_rails:install" without "sunspot_rails" in the Gemfile. Also, since you mentioned that you have already worked on a project with sunspot_solr. Do you know any good resources for a ruby beginner? It would be a lot of help. Thanks

Comment: According to the docs (https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot/tree/master/sunspot_rails) you should leave `sunspot_rails` rather than `sunspot_solr`, so I  may have it 'wrong' (but it works, strange). However, if I've added both of them my bundle completes sucessfully, but I have installed `bundler 1.3.5 and 1.1.1`. About resources: StackOverflow and Apache wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/

Comment: @naka: yes, I saw your response, glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'sunspot_rails'
```

gem 'sunspot_solr' is optional as mentioned [here](http://sunspot.github.io/docs/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Delete the Gemfile.lock and run bundle install, letting Bundler resolve all the dependencies from scratch.

Comment: vamsi : there is no Gemfile.lock in the directory where I'm doing bundle install

Comment: Neither for myself, when I attempted to duplicate this issue.  I get the same message as well, so it seems to not be a problem with your system.  Did you check issues on the affected gems?